# How to use same Authenticated user token between main iOS app and its Share Extension

Tags: ios, firebase-authentication, ios-app-extension, ios-app-group

We have the main app integrated with Firebase SDK. User sign in via main application using email, google or facebook.

Now, we have share extension implemented which ideally should share same Authentication session internally so that data can be sent on Firebase with the same user without asking him to login again through the extension.

So, does anyone know the way to share Firebase authentication session between the Main app and share extension?

1. Either we sent some internal call to the main app to perform Firebase stuff because it has authentication detail within it.
2. The main app set some token to common user defaults via app groups which will be then used by Share extension to re-authenticate automatically.
3. Or Firebase provide some way to do so,

I don't know what is feasible from above.
I found a method `signInWithCustomToken:completion:` but, it's not related to what I actually looking for.

Comment: Any update on this ? I meet the same situation...

Answer (score -1):

To read and save from the same set of NSUserDefaults you need to the the following:

1. In your main app, select your project in the project navigator.
2. Select your main app target and choose the capabilities tab.
3. Switch on App Groups (this will communicate with the developer portal, as it is generating a set of entitlements, and relevant App Id and so
   forth).
4. Create a new container. According to the help, it must start
   with “group.”, so give it a name like “group.myapp.test”.
5. Select
   your Today Extension target and repeat this process of switching on
   app groups. Don’t create a new one, rather select this newly created
   group to signify that the Today Extension is a member of the group.

Write to your NSUserDefaults:

```
    // In this example I´m setting FirstLaunch value to true 
NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.myapp.test")!.setBool(true, forKey: "FirstLaunch")
```

Read from NSUserDefaults:

```
// Getting the value from FirstLaunch
let firstLaunch = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.myapp.test")!.boolForKey("FirstLaunch")

if !firstLaunch  {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Sir, actually I know how to share data between main app & Extension. my problem is to use same authentication session between main app & extension.

Comment: You have any authentication token for it ? If not, then you can directly save a property in user defaults, "isUserAuthenticated" and skip the authentication in extension.
If you have a authentication token, then you can save it in user defaults and share it with the extension to validate if the token is valid.

Comment: This is not the solution. I actually looking for some way to share Firebase session between main app & extension. Kindly please go through the Question.